# How many bits per channel we have for storing vertex color data?

Tags: vertex-colors

As in title. I want to know how precise vertex color data is in Blender.

Comment: As far as I know they are the standard 24bit RGB

Comment: Thanks for answer. Only 8 bits per channel is quite small.

Comment: If you need more detail you may use vertex groups which are float values I think.